# redirect url after selecting option in HTML form?

Tags: html

I have a simple `form` with `options` that I want to redirect to.
In the root of my `index.html` which has the following code. I have two folders in same level as `index.html`. `foo/index.html` and `bar/index.html`. I want to redirect to sub-index.html upon option selection and submit. NOT `onchange` event.

```
<form id='selector'>
      <div class='input'>
        <select id="foobarid" name="foobar">
            <option value="foo/index.html">foo</option>
            <option value="bar/index.html">bar</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class='input'><a id="foobarsubmit" href="#">submit</a></div>
    </form>
```

**NOTE**: most posts explains using `jquery/javascript`. I am trying to see if it is possible to avoid using `jquery/javascript` event handlers.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to handle it with the onchange event?

Comment: @Phil-R: the requirement is to be redirected upon clicking the submit button. not just onchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the href of the submit element to the option value onchange of the select
something like

```
<form id='selector'>
      <div class='input'>
        <select id="foobarid" name="foobar" 
                onchange="document.getElementById('foobarsubmit').href = this.value;">
            <option value="foo/index.html">foo</option>
            <option value="bar/index.html">bar</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class='input'><a id="foobarsubmit" href="#">submit</a></div>
</form>
```